# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\admin\Auth' not found in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, runtime-error

I am getting error like Class `App\Http\Controllers\admin\Auth` not found in Laravel 5 during login.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin'),function(){
    Route::get('login', 'admin\AdminHomeController@showLogin');
    Route::post('check','admin\AdminHomeController@checkLogin');    
});
```

**AdminHomeController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminHomeController extends Controller {

    //
    
    public function showLogin()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }
    
    public function checkLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $data=array(
            'username'=>$request->get('username'),
            'password'=>$request->get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($data))
        {
            return redirect::intended('admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }
        
    }
    
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
    public function showDashboard()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<html>
<body>
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/check', 'id' => 'login')) !!}
        
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter any username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter any password" />
                <button name="submit">Sign In</button>
            
        {!! Form::close() !!}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because your controller is namespaced unless you specifically import the `Auth` namespace, PHP will assume it's under the namespace of the class, giving this error.

To fix this, add `use Auth;` at the top of `AdminHomeController` file along with your other use statements or alternatively prefix all instances of `Auth` with backslash like this: `\Auth` to let PHP know to load it from the global namespace.

Comment: but it i dont know why it goes to else condition                                                     public function checkLogin(Request $request)
 {
  $data=array(
   'username'=>$request->get('username'),
   'password'=>$request->get('password')
  );
  if(Auth::attempt($data))
  {
   echo "i am not coming over here";die;
   return redirect::intended('admin/dashboard');
  }
  else
  {
   echo "always comes here";die;
   return redirect('admin/login');
  } 
 }

Comment: in auth.php file 'table' => 'sysadmin' and in sysadmin there is only two fields "username" primary key & "password"